# I am having issues running javascript on sublime text

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance, sublimetext3

I just started my JavaScript course but I am having issues running JavaScript code.
Note: I built a system and I have nodejs but my system is giving me issues:

[image: The issue I am having with Sublime Text]

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please post text, not links to images of text. The issue seems reasonably clear; `node` is either not installed, or not on your path.

Answer (score 2):

Open windows search bar and look for, "Environment Variables", open it and look for "path" variable for current user and if there isn't a path like below, add one.

```
C:\Users\<your username here>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

If it still doesn't work then you probably didn't install NodeJS correctly. Install Node again.
Open CMD, type "node" and press Enter. If it gives a response like "Welcome to Node ...". There you have it, it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the picture you uploaded,
I feel like you trying to run your node directly from your sublime console
and it not properly install

visit this link https://pawelgrzybek.com/javascript-console-in-sublime-text/

Comment: You are life saver... I was supposed to save it /nodejs/ instead I used node.js... Thank you, please if you have a way I can also run JavaScript on vs code too let me know... God bless you

Comment: To run node in VS code isn't quite hard either. it don't require any form of installation, Just make such Node Js is install globally on your machain ().then use `ctrl + '`  to open your terminal directly in VS code - if this answer all your questions please press the answer button above